"Remix vite: build" not found while building docker
I'm new to Docker and Remix and having problems figuring out how to deploy Remix on Docker.
When I build the Docker it stops at RUN npm run build and gives this error
> build
> remix vite:build

sh: 1: remix: not found

My docker file
FROM node:20-bullseye-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssl sqlite3

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --omit=dev

RUN npx prisma generate

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000
ENV DATABASE_URL=file:./dev.db
ENV PORT=3000
ENV NODE_ENV=production
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]

My package.json
{
  "name": "film-ranking",
  "private": true,
  "sideEffects": false,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "remix vite:build",
    "dev": "remix vite:dev",
    "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --cache --cache-location ./node_modules/.cache/eslint .",
    "start": "remix-serve ./build/server/index.js",
    "typecheck": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@picocss/pico": "^2.0.6",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.15.0",
    "@remix-run/node": "^2.9.2",
    "@remix-run/react": "^2.9.2",
    "@remix-run/serve": "^2.9.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "isbot": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.2.1",
    "remix": "^2.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@remix-run/dev": "^2.9.2",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.4",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "prisma": "^5.15.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "^5.1.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=20.0.0"
  }
}

I have tried adding npm install remix and it solved the issue but it says that it is deprecate so I would like to use a different solution.
I appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks.

You initially RUN npm install --omit=dev, but you probably need the devDependencies to npm run build.

@DavidMaze Thanks. Now it works with RUN npm install but it takes 1000+ seconds to finish. For now it's ok but not ideal. Do you know a possible solution?. Thanks again.
